# During aggregation count the longest date streak - using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, time-series, aws-glue

imagine a table:

| PersonID | Date | HasDoneWorkout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 31-01-2001 | 1 |
| A | 01-02-2001 | 1 |
| A | 02-02-2001 | 1 |
| A | 03-02-2001 | 0 |
| A | 04-02-2001 | 1 |
| B | 02-02-2001 | 1 |

I would like to create a pyspark aggregation function which will count how many days in a row a person has done workout. If person has more than one consecutive record - pick the longest one.

Expected output:

| PersonID | HasDoneWorkout |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |

Since I didn't find any solution using pyspark - I tried to adopt a pandas approach. But failed to translate it into pyspark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step by step solution

Create a window specification to group the DataFrame by `PersonID` and order by `Date` then using the `to_date` function to parse the strings as date type.

```
W = Window.partitionBy('PersonID').orderBy('Date')
df1 = df.withColumn('Date', F.to_date('Date', format='dd-MM-yyyy'))

# df1.show()
# +--------+----------+--------------+
# |PersonID|      Date|HasDoneWorkout|
# +--------+----------+--------------+
# |       A|2001-01-31|             1|
# |       A|2001-02-01|             1|
# |       A|2001-02-02|             1|
# |       A|2001-02-03|             0|
# |       A|2001-02-04|             1|
# |       B|2001-02-02|             1|
# +--------+----------+--------------+
```

Calculate the difference between the Dates in the previous and current row to flag the rows where dates are consecutive

```
diff = F.datediff('Date', F.lag('Date').over(W))
df1 = df1.withColumn('is_consecutive_day', F.coalesce(diff, F.lit(0)) == 1)

# df1.show()
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
# |PersonID|      Date|HasDoneWorkout|is_consecutive_day|
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
# |       A|2001-01-31|             1|             false|
# |       A|2001-02-01|             1|              true|
# |       A|2001-02-02|             1|              true|
# |       A|2001-02-03|             0|              true|
# |       A|2001-02-04|             1|              true|
# |       B|2001-02-02|             1|             false|
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

Create a boolean column to identify the rows with consecutive dates and the rows where the person has done the workout.

```
df1 = df1.withColumn('is_workout_on_consecutive_day', F.col('is_consecutive_day') & (F.col('HasDoneWorkout') == 1))

# df1.show()
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
# |PersonID|      Date|HasDoneWorkout|is_consecutive_day|is_workout_on_consecutive_day|
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
# |       A|2001-01-31|             1|             false|                        false|
# |       A|2001-02-01|             1|              true|                         true|
# |       A|2001-02-02|             1|              true|                         true|
# |       A|2001-02-03|             0|              true|                        false|
# |       A|2001-02-04|             1|              true|                         true|
# |       B|2001-02-02|             1|             false|                        false|
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Cumulative sum over the inverted condition `is_workout_on_consecutive_day` to distinguish between different groups of rows where person has done workout consecutively

```
df1 = df1.withColumn('groups', F.sum((~F.col('is_workout_on_consecutive_day')).cast('int')).over(W))


# df1.show()
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------+------+
# |PersonID|      Date|HasDoneWorkout|is_consecutive_day|is_workout_on_consecutive_day|groups|
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------+------+
# |       A|2001-01-31|             1|             false|                        false|     1|
# |       A|2001-02-01|             1|              true|                         true|     1|
# |       A|2001-02-02|             1|              true|                         true|     1|
# |       A|2001-02-03|             0|              true|                        false|     2|
# |       A|2001-02-04|             1|              true|                         true|     2|
# |       B|2001-02-02|             1|             false|                        false|     1|
# +--------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------+------+
```

Group the dataframe by `PersonID` and `groups` and aggregate `HasDoneWorkout` with `sum` to get the counts of all consecutive streaks

```
df1 = df1.groupBy('PersonID', 'groups').agg(F.sum('HasDoneWorkout').alias('streaks'))

# df1.show()
# +--------+------+-------+
# |PersonID|groups|streaks|
# +--------+------+-------+
# |       A|     1|      3|
# |       A|     2|      1|
# |       B|     1|      1|
# +--------+------+-------+
```

Again group the dataframe by `PersonID` and aggregate to find the maximum continuous streak

```
df1 = df1.groupBy('PersonID').agg(F.max('streaks').alias('streaks'))

# df1.show()
# +--------+-------+
# |PersonID|streaks|
# +--------+-------+
# |       A|      3|
# |       B|      1|
# +--------+-------+
```